# VirtualBox seamless integration - virtual Windows in another KDE desktop

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox, virtualization, kde-plasma

My OS is Fedora 21 with KDE 4. I use virtual Windows 8, run it with VirtualBox. Is there a way to somehow place my Fedora appearance at one desktop (workplace, room, i'm not really a KDE specialist) and virtual Windows 8 at another? 
I tried to use two different KDE rooms, but Windows 8 integrates into both of them.
Thanks

Comment: I don't have a virtual Win8, but with 7 and xp, I put them fullscreen on the 2nd desktop, then press host key (R-CTRL for me) then CTRL+F1 to switch to kde; CTRL+F2 to switch back to windows

Comment: didn't work for me :( Nothing happens when I press CTRL+F1/F2